# Laravel 4 @foreach

Tags: laravel-4

Using a resourceful UsersController and $users.

It seems that when $users has only 1 entry, the @foreach loop doesn't work?

In UsersController:

```
public function show($id) {
   $users = User::find($id);
   return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);
}
```

If I just use "return $users", the value of $users is:

```
{"id":"1","username":"user1"}
```

In users.blade.php:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{$user->username}}
@endforeach
```

When there are 2 or more users it worked, but with URI app.com/users/1, it only returns one (see above) and the new error is:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Why is this an error in users.blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a question of what `User::find($id)` is returning..

[Query builder methods return an instance of the `Collection`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Builder.html#_get) class, which represents a collection of Models.  For instance, here we get back a Collection containing one Model.

```
$users = User::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
```

However the `find()` method [returns a single `Model`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Builder.html#_find)

```
$users = User::find($id);
```

A single `Model` isn't iterable in the same way as a `Collection`, which returns a Model with each iteration, hence the error you're seeing!